# Random mic permission popup after configuring AdMob

Tags: ios, permissions, admob

After installing AdMob framework with cocoapods and configuring reward video ad my app started to ask for Microphone permission on launch. I don't do any audio-related stuff in it so it's a very little chance I have triggered it myself outside of AdMob framework... Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: We are having the same issue. Any fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

**You can get rid of this following this steps:**

1. Go to "Security & Privacy" Settings on macOS.
2. Select "Microphone" on the left panel.
3. Uncheck the Xcode option on the right panel.